# When to remove Skeleton screen in component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, vue.js

I about to do content loader (Skeleton screen) in my spa application (vue/angular/webcomponent) like youtube:

[image]

When I load the some component I display the Skeleton.

My question is should I remove the Skeleton after component **and the images** inside are loaded (downloaded and ready to display) or after the content is ready to display and the images are not (the request is send but not resolved yet)?

Answer (score 1):

For a better user experience you should wait until the component and the images are loaded.

Comment: You could post this in comment instead of an answer  :)